# Creating initial wiki for new repositories

Tags: git, api, github, github-api

I'm creating multiple private repositories via GitHub API that should include predefined wiki pages. Wiki pages are handled via a separate git repository.

Unfortunately creating a repository with the `has_wiki` flag turned on does not set up the wiki repository automatically. The Home document only seems to be created when I click on the *Pages* section of the wiki in the web front end. Before that there is no wiki clone URL which I need to push my custom pages.

How can I create the wiki programmatically?

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible currently, I believe. I'll add this to The List and mention it to the team, but can't make any promises about if/when that might be possible.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thanks a lot. Would be great if you could give me an update. Meanwhile I will have to add this manual step.

Comment: Sure thing -- I've made a note to ping you here when this ability is provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitnami Gitlab server either local or remote. It has all the features you require. 
Its free and very simple to use.

Comment: For this scenario I need to stick to GitHub.